# Bind Data to Template Defined in <script> Tag in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-templates

I am trying to bind data to angular template. But I'm facing the following issue.

I am using $templateCache to retrieve the template but I cannot find data into the template.

```
$templateCache.get('q1.index.html');
```

Now, I am also trying to do `$compile($templateCache.get('q1.index.html'));` but I am getting `Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/jqLite/nosel` error.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong & how can I resolve it.

Comment: Can you add the complete code or atleast the JS which injects the $templateCache into your angular controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this format for your `<script>` tag

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
  <p>This is the content of the template</p>
</script>
```

then somewhere else you can retrieve with `$templateCache`

```
$templateCache.get('templateId.html')
```

Or via `ng-include`

```
<div ng-include="'templateId.html'"></div>
```